# Southern California nature day trips?

Tags: public-transport, southern-california, nature-and-wildlife, day-trips

I'm going for a visit to LA and Anaheim (first time in US) in about 3 weeks time and I was frantically looking for something significant to visit while there preferably on a day trip. I'm a nature lover and not too into tourist traps, so hate the idea of Hollywood and celebrities. I found out that the world's oldest tree resides in [Methuselah Grove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Bristlecone_Pine_Forest) in the [White Mountains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Mountains_%28California%29).

My questions:

1. I read on Wikipedia that [Methuselah (the tree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah_%28tree%29) is unmarked to protect it from vandals. I can understand that. But is it safe to assume that it is even *in* Methuselah Grove?
2. If I'm staying in Anaheim, how feasible is it to take a day trip out there? With public transport?
3. Any other suggestions on what to see, along similar lines that can be accomplished in a day on public transport?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things about California that are simply difficult concepts for people to get their heads around. It doesn't matter whether or not you've been to the US before; even if you've lived in the eastern US your whole life, you'll still get bit by these when visiting California. Here's two of them:

- **Public transit**
  You can generally get from one part of an urban area to another part of the same urban area (within, say, 30-50 miles) by public transit. Going a longer distance than that, or going to a suburban area (much less rural), or going to another county? At that point, it's sheer luck.
- **Distances**
  While places may look nearby on a map, they aren't. Anaheim, for instance, is *not* in Los Angeles; it's not even in LA County. People who live in one go to the other as a day trip. Google maps says it takes [about 2.5 hours each way by bus](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Anaheim,+CA&daddr=Los+Angeles,+CA&vpsrc=0&dirflg=rB&ttype=dep&date=08%2F25%2F11&time=12:00pm).

A trip from Anaheim to [Inyo National Forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyo_National_Forest) is about [240 miles or 4-5 hours by car, each way](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Anaheim,+CA&daddr=Inyo+National+Forest). I doubt that there's a way to do it via public transportation at all.

Based on what you've said you like, I recommend that you check out [Laguna Coast Wilderness Park](http://www.ocparks.com/lagunacoast/). Google Maps says it should take [about 2 hours by bus](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Anaheim,+CA&daddr=Laguna+Coast+Wilderness+Park,+California+133,+Laguna+Beach,+CA&dirflg=r&ttype=dep&date=08%2F25%2F11&time=12:00pm) each way. It looks like once you get there, you're in for [nice hiking trails and views](http://www.yelp.com/biz/laguna-coast-wilderness-park-laguna-beach).

Comment: +1 thanks for the advice, i did not realize that public transport was that bad. I've been getting advice from friends to just rent a car anyway (regardless of what i'll be doing) so i think i might do just that. Laguna Coast wilderness park looks perfect by the way :)

Answer (score 6):

Inyo Park is more than 4 hours from LA... in okay traffic. I would not say it is really a day trip. I used to live in Barstow (which is closer to it than LA) and it was quite a trip from there.

As for other attractions, it depends on what you would like to do.

There are the beaches, Santa Monica or Huntington being my favorite.
The Getty center is a great museum, although it is better known for just looking generally awesome.
I also think Santa Barbara is a great place to visit. It is a nice town.